# MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have read many articles according to my issue, but I stiil have no solution.

When I try to create connection to WebSpereMQ I get

```
MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009
```

After reading different articles I tried to change CCSID by doing

```
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.CCSID_PROPERTY, 1208); 
// also tried other CCSIDs like 1200,819,500
```

but I had no success. Than I read that a good idea is to look at MQ log files to find out if there is another process wich interrupt the connection. But I am not able to investigate that log files since they are encoded and I don't how to read them.

Questions:
1) Do you know how to read MQ logs? How to make them readable?
2) Do you know what else could cause that kind of problem?

Logs from file AMQERR01.txt :

```
----- amqxfdcp.c : 773 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:01 - Process(2880.3) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20806211)

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the MQ error recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 735 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:01 - Process(2880.3) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager MMSG01Q2.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 2880.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 773 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20806211)

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the MQ error recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 735 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager MMSG01Q2.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 2880.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 773 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20806211)

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the MQ error recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 735 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager MMSG01Q2.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 2880.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 773 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20806211)

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the MQ error recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 735 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager MMSG01Q2.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 2880.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 773 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20806211)

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the MQ error recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 735 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:41:05 - Process(2880.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(javaw.exe)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager MMSG01Q2.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 2880.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 773 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:45:41 - Process(3192.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(crtmqm.exe)
AMQ6119: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (Failed to create mapped
memory segment: [rc=536895769 errorCode=5])

EXPLANATION:
MQ detected an unexpected error when calling the operating system. The MQ error
recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 735 --------------------------------------------------------
04.07.2013 10:45:41 - Process(3192.1) User(Anton.Kasianchuk) Program(crtmqm.exe)
AMQ6183: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 3192.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier, and to save the generated output files. Contact your IBM support
center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 779 --
```

logs from file amqtsivt.txt

```
10:45:39 IVT Started

10:45:41 Setup IVT Environment...

10:45:41 Creating Queue Manager...

10:45:42 Starting Queue Manager...

10:45:42 Ready.

10:45:42 Connect to QueueManager(1), CC:2 - RC:2058

10:45:42 Connect to QueueManager(2), CC:2 - RC:2058

10:45:42 Open queue, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 Put Message, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 Message Put: AMQMTSIVT

10:45:42 Get Message, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 Message Returned: 

10:45:42 Close queue, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 Started thread 01

10:45:42 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:42 Child Thread finished 43 cycles

10:45:43 Started thread 02

10:45:43 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:43 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:43 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:43 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:43 Child Thread finished 46 cycles

10:45:44 Started thread 03

10:45:44 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:44 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:44 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:44 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:44 Child Thread finished 49 cycles

10:45:45 Started thread 04

10:45:45 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 Child Thread finished 3 cycles

10:45:45 Started thread 05

10:45:45 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 Child Thread finished 3 cycles

10:45:45 Started thread 06

10:45:45 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 Child Thread finished 3 cycles

10:45:45 Started thread 07

10:45:45 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 Child Thread finished 3 cycles

10:45:45 Started thread 08

10:45:45 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:45 Child Thread finished 3 cycles

10:45:46 Started thread 09

10:45:46 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:46 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:46 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:46 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:46 Child Thread finished 6 cycles

10:45:47 User cancelled action

10:45:47 Started thread 10

10:45:47 MQOpen in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:47 MQPut in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:47 MQGet in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:47 MQClose in Child Thread, CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:47 Child Thread finished 9 cycles

10:45:48 Error(s) encountered during thread execution

10:45:48 All threads terminated

10:45:48 Disconnect from QueueManager (1), CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:48 Disconnect from QueueManager (2), CC:2 - RC:2018

10:45:48 Ready.

10:45:49 Cleaning Up...

10:45:49 Deleting MTS Package

10:45:49 Access MTS Admin Catalog, OK

10:45:52 Get MTS Packages, OK

10:45:52 Ending Queue Manager...

10:45:52 Deleting Queue Manager...

10:45:53 Ready.
```

logs from \Qmgrs\MMSG01Q2\errors\AMQERR01.txt

```
----- amqrmrsa.c : 468 --------------------------------------------------------
05.07.2013 09:41:10 - Process(6004.21) User(j2mquser) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
AMQ9502: Type of channel not suitable for action requested.

EXPLANATION:
The operation requested cannot be performed on channel 'CLOUD.MMSG01Q2.S1'.
Some operations are only valid for certain channel types. For example, you can
only ping a channel from the end sending the message.
ACTION:
Check whether the channel name is specified correctly.  If it is check that the
channel has been defined correctly. 
----- amqrmsaa.c : 1072 -------------------------------------------------------
05.07.2013 09:41:10 - Process(6004.21) User(j2mquser) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
AMQ9999: Channel program ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
Channel program 'CLOUD.MMSG01Q2.S1' ended abnormally.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for channel program 'CLOUD.MMSG01Q2.S1' in the
error files to determine the cause of the failure. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 468 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

What logs are you referring to? MQ Error logs are not in binary. You can find them under (on Windows) WebSphere MQ installation folder. Error logs specific to queue manager will be under \Qmgrs\"qmgr"\ folder. Please look at these error logs, they may have information regarding your problem.

Check if the port that you are using in application is the one queue manager is listening on. Do you have SSL enabled on the queue manager port and your application does not use SSL?

Comment: You were right about logs. Now I've added error logs to my question. But as for me they doesn't have a lot of information. Can you look on it? You were talking about that kind of logs, right?

Comment: And yes, the port I am using in my app is the same as the one in queue manager.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in OS I used? We have two machines (Windows7 and WindowsXP) with the same software and we use the same software configuration. But when it is working fine on XP, it is failing on Windows 7.

Comment: MQRC 2058 means the queue manager name provided is not valid. MQRC 2018 means MQRC_HCONN_ERROR is follow up error because the earlier call to create a connection failed with 2058.

Comment: MQRC 2058 means the queue manager name provided is not valid. MQRC 2018 means MQRC_HCONN_ERROR is follow up error because the earlier call to create a connection failed with 2058. Is MMSG01Q2 the queue manager you are trying to connect to? Have you specified the queue manager name is correct case?

Comment: I can assure you I'm trying to connect to MMSG01Q2 and moreover it is started fine. One more thing: I was wrong about operating systems issue - we cannot create connection neither in WindowsXP nor in Windows7.

Comment: It seems some useful information is in the \Qmgrs\MMSG01Q2\errors\AMQERR01.txt. It looks like I am using wrong channel type. (This logs were added to my question)

Answer (score 1):

I use this for client mode connections
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQConstants.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I added next code:

```
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS);
```

Comment: Good find. This code makes your application to use shared memory to communicate with queue manager. This will work as long as both application and queue manager are the same machine. For application to connect via channel, the channel must be of SVRCONN (Server connection) type. So please check if the channel you are using is of  SVRCONN type.